# SQL Server Grouping unrelated records according to row value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, grouping, row-number

How can I group repeating records?

I have a single column that denotes whether a record is a start, end or a detail record. Detail Records are records that exist after a start record and before a end record.

I want to group these records together with a unique identifier so that each time there is a end record the next series of records get a new group id.

I've tried a series of self joins, sub queries and cte's
Without building a custom function, view or CTE I'm hoping to build this in a single select query.

Any advice or pointers much appreciated.

Example before solution:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| ID      | RecordType    |  SomeValue
--------------------------------------------------
|001      | Start record  |  some header info
|002      | Detail Record |  value
|003      | Detail Record |  value
|004      | Detail Record |  value
|005      | End Record    |  some other header info
|006      | Start Record  |  some header info
|007      | Detail Record |  Value
|008      | End  Record   |  some other header info
```

What I've trying to achieve:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
| ID      | RecordType    |  SomeValue             | RecordGroup
------------------------------------------------------------------
|001      | Start record  |  some header info      | 001
|002      | Detail Record |  value                 | 001
|003      | Detail Record |  value                 | 001
|004      | Detail Record |  value                 | 001
|005      | End Record    |  some other header info| 001
|006      | Start Record  |  some header info      | 002
|007      | Detail Record |  Value                 | 002
|008      | End  Record   |  some other header info| 002
```

Comment: Google SQL Island and gaps problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `LAG` function and running `SUM`. The following assumes that there is no partitioning and rows are ordered by ID:

```
SELECT ID, RecordType, SomeValue,
       SUM(chg) OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS grp
FROM (
    SELECT ID, RecordType, SomeValue,
           CASE WHEN LAG(RecordType) OVER (ORDER BY ID) IN ('Start record', 'Detail Record') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS chg
    FROM t
) cte1
```

[**Demo on DB Fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ef46b62ab421d18a966b87716b5d27b8)

Comment: Will give this a go many thanks for your help, will add this to my script library.

Comment: @Flat_Cap_Hat [this is how you say thanks](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)... if it helped of course.